# Migrate website away from cPanel but keep email on cPanel?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I'm new to cPanel/WHM and have relatively basic knowledge of MX records/mail routing, so bear with me if I'm missing something obvious.

I've a new customer who has a VPS with cPanel/WHM installed. Currently it runs their DNS, website and email.

I'm migrating their website away to a new server and eventually I'll be doing the same for their email.

However I need to keep their email hosted on cPanel for the time being once their website is fully migrated.

Currently the DNS records are as follows:

```
+-------------+-------+--------------+----------+--+
|    name     | type  |   location   | priority |  |
+-------------+-------+--------------+----------+--+
| domain.com. | A     | ip.ad.dr.ess |          |  |
| www         | CNAME | domain.com   |          |  |
| domain.com. | MX    | domain.com.  |        0 |  |
+-------------+-------+--------------+----------+--+
```

I realise I need to repoint the main A record to my new server for switching the website, which is fine. However I'm assuming that will break the existing MX record (and hence their mail routing) as that's using the domain.com record to route mail to the current IP address?

So if I create a new A record called something like `mailserver.domain.com` which is pointed at the original IP address and then point the MX record at `mailserver.domain.com`, will that mean their email continues to work as expected?

Or is there something about cPanel/WHM which will mean that because the MX record is not pointing at the naked primary domain that it'll no longer route the email?

I've not tried anything yet which I realise is bad form but don't want to screw their email routing up while experimenting with DNS updates.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've proposed will work fine.  What you need to do after you click "confirm" is to make sure the reverse DNS settings are still all happy.

Go to https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx and punch in the root domain (domain.com) and click "MX Lookup".  When it comes up with the proper server name & ip combo, click 'SMTP test'.  This will tell you if reverse DNS is still correct.  It should be completely fine, but you can never be too sure with email.  Maybe run theses tests beforehand so you have a baseline to compare against.

Before you do the cutover, it might be a good idea to turn down all your TTL values so you don't have to wait around for it to propagate.

Comment: Thanks Neil. That's useful. The question has been put on hold because it mentions the server is running cPanel but this seems like purely a DNS thing to me. Anyway, I'll do as you suggest and ensure the reverse DNS settings mimic what is there at the moment.

Comment: Made changes as suggested and all appears to be working.